# Expressing Constraints Formally

Tags: database-design, constraint

I have been asked a question related to database constraints. I am familiar with Oracle DDLs and DMLs and know how to define FK, PK and standard constraints related to relations / tables using DDL.

What I am not so sure of was when I was asked to present constraints formally using Relational Calculus.

So my question is:

Can someone provide an example of a simple constraint expressed formally using Relational Calculus?

Comment: I am making reference to domain relational calculus

Comment: Please put that in to your question; comments are ephemeral. Also if you want an example in the variant you are you using you have to tell us what it is.

Answer (score 2):

Relational calculus is a notation for expressing relation values in terms of given named relations and sometimes constants. So is relational algebra. A constraint is an expression making a statement about one or more relation values. But such a statement is not relation-valued, so you can't express it in relation-valued notation alone. (So you need to ask what exactly is wanted.)

You have to have operators returning equality of relations, or whether a relation is empty, etc. (Either of those two is sufficient.)

```
-- every teacher is a person
empty({<id>|(exists class Teaches(id, class)) and not Person(id)})
```

A query is typically like `{tuple|formula}`. You could use an expression like the formula part of a query if you consider any free variables/attributes to be implicitly universally quantified. (This is also sufficient.)

```
-- id is a superkey of Teaches
-- forall id, c1, c2
    Teaches(id, c1) and Teaches(id, c2) implies c1=c2
```

(`empty({<...>|`*`formula`*`})` is the same as `forall ... not`*`formula`*.)